# How do I use current_page? to reference a mounted engine path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I use :class =>('active' if current_page?desired_path) to add a selected tag to navigation links if we're looking at that current page:

```
<%= link_to "Portfolio", portfolio_path, :class =>('active' if current_page?portfolio_path) %>
```

I want this functionality to work with a page that points to a mounted engine.  From my routes.rb:

```
mount Blogit::Engine => "/blog"
```

I want to do something like this:

```
<%= link_to "Blog", blogit_path, :class =>('active' if current_page?blogit_path) %>
```

. . .  but apparently blogit_path isn't the appropriate path as my class is never set to active.  I have also tried `current_page?('/blog')` since I'm at the url http://myapp.com/blog - but even that doesn't work.

Note that `current_page?blog_root_path` works as long as I'm within the blog engine's path.  I get errors if I'm outside of the engine.

How do I use current_page to reference a mounted engine path?

Here are the associated `rake routes` results:

```
. . .
blogit        /blog                          Blogit::Engine
                    root GET    /                              home#index
         portfolio_index GET    /portfolio(.:format)           portfolio#index
               portfolio GET    /portfolio(.:format)           portfolio#index

Routes for Blogit::Engine:
              GET    /posts/page/:page(.:format)            blogit/posts#index
post_comments POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)     blogit/comments#create
 post_comment DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format) blogit/comments#destroy
        posts GET    /posts(.:format)                       blogit/posts#index
              POST   /posts(.:format)                       blogit/posts#create
     new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                   blogit/posts#new
    edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)              blogit/posts#edit
         post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#show
              PATCH  /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#update
              PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#update
              DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                   blogit/posts#destroy
    blog_root GET    /                                      blogit/posts#index
```

Comment: For any wondering, :class =>('active' if (request.path.include? '/blog/') works as a work-around, but it's not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I have limited knowledge of mountable engines. I have been recently looking at this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/277-mountable-engines) though and it may help.

Following that, it could be that you need to pass in an `as` option to the mountable engine in your routes file, eg:

```
mount Blogit::Engine => "/blog", as: "blogit_engine"
```

Then, when in your main app, your path helper for blogit root should be:

```
blogit_engine.root_url
```

Which would lead, in your case to:

```
<%= link_to "Blog", blogit_path, :class =>('active' if current_page?blogit_engine.root_url) %>
```

Comment: After making the routing changes - blogit_path is an undefined variable outside of the engine, and an undefined method for the module within the engine.  If I change blogit_path to blogit_engine_path, the link works.  But blogit_engine.root_url gives an undefined method error.  If I change blogit_engine.root_url to something like blogit_path - we have the same behavior as before: no error, but the active class is never applied.

Comment: I found the same thing; scoping problem?

Comment: Oh, I'm using Mercury and it turns out Mercury was opening the page in an iframe, so the routes weren't what I expected them to be.